# How to parse varying amounts of lines from a text file in Python?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text-files

I'm trying to write a simple parser that grabs multiline blocks of text from one .txt file and copies it to a new .txt file. Why (I think) my problem differs from similar questions posted on-line is that the number of lines varies depending on the block of text, so I require some way of identifying where the desired block of text begins and ends.

Consider this minimal example of an input file:

```
NAME_1{a bunch of text|more text}
 1  -22.17
1 lol //
2 wtf //
NA_ME2{text|text}
 1  -25.50
1 gtfo //
NAME3{text|text}
 1  -17.50
1 brb //
2 lol //
3 wtf //
```

I want my parser to output a text file with NAME_1 with all its related information and NAME3 with all its related information. I want my output text file to read:

```
NAME_1{a bunch of text|more text}
 1  -22.17
1 lol //
2 wtf //
NAME3{text|text}
 1  -17.50
1 brb //
2 lol //
3 wtf //
```

I have a parser that works but is problematic (and inefficient, but I'm new to this). Specifically, the majority of the blocks of text I require are 43 lines in length, so my parser identifies a required name and then grabs that line and the next 42 lines of text. But this is a problem because some blocks of text are not 43 lines in length. This is what I have so far:

```
import re

infile = open('input.txt')
outfile = open('output.txt', 'w')

# Appends all needed names into a list
nameList = []
with open('list.txt') as f:
for name in f:
    n = name.strip()
    nameList.append(n)

# Finds required name from example txt file and outputs that line and the next 42   
lines = infile.readlines()
for line in range(0,len(lines)):
    for l in nameList:
        if l in lines[line]:
         [outfile.write(part) for part in lines[line:line+42]]
```

The list.txt file contains the following:

```
NAME_1{
NAME3{
```

I think regular expression could solve my problem. `'([A-Z]\w+){'` will locate the beginning of each block of text, so I imagine there must be some way to determine if the RE match is equivalent to an item of `nameList`, and then to parse every line until -- but not including -- the next match of `'([A-Z]\w+){'`. This way it shouldn't matter how long a block of text is. Is it possible to identifying where a desired block of text begins and ends using regular expressions in this way?

Thanks.

EDIT: Each block of text begins with the occurrence of the regular expression `'([A-Z]\w+){'`. Hence, the example input file contains three blocks of text where the lines with NAME_1, NA_ME2 and NAME3 represent the first line of each block.

Comment: When does a block end?

Comment: Each block of text begins with each occurrence of the regular expression `'([A-Z]\w+){'`. In other words, in my example text file, NAME_1 is the start of the first block, NA_ME2 is the start of the second block and NAME3 is the start of the third block.

Comment: So you can identify each block by matching this regex. If the block is one of those you are interested in, output it. If not, continue until you reach the next interesting block.

Comment: Logically this makes sense to me, but I'm a beginning and seeking suggestions of how to do that. I've searched stackoverlow for hours and cannot solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

s = """NAME_1{a bunch of text|more text}
 1  -22.17
1 lol //
2 wtf //
NA_ME2{text|text}
 1  -25.50
1 gtfo //
NAME3{text|text}
 1  -17.50
1 brb //
2 lol //
3 wtf //
"""

guards = ["NAME_1", "NAME3"]    
r = re.compile(r"^([A-Z][A-Z0-9_]+){")
printing = False

for line in s.splitlines():
    m = r.match(line)
    if m:
        if m.groups(1) and m.groups(1)[0] in guards:
            printing = True
        else:
            printing = False
    if printing:
        print(line.strip())
```

Output:

```
NAME_1{a bunch of text|more text}
1  -22.17
1 lol //
2 wtf //
NAME3{text|text}
1  -17.50
1 brb //
2 lol //
3 wtf //
```

Comment: Thanks Lutz, the help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, one brief follow-up question. I've read my input.txt file in to Python as a string in place of your `s` variable, and replaced the `print(line.strip())` command with `outfile.write(line.strip())`, where `outfile = open('output.txt', 'w')`. Although this parses the desired output text, it enters output.txt on a single line. Is everything on a single line because of `strip()`? I thought if left blank it only removes white space.

Comment: After much effort I solved my problem. It appears `splitlines()` was causing the problem. Thanks again!